# Multipart/form-data with raw request body sending document

Tags: rest, pdf, encoding, base64, multipartform-data

I'm trying to figure out how to send a PDF Document to a Server via Rest but I want to achive this with only raw request body in Postman:

RAW Body in Postman:

```
------verycreativeboundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

144
------verycreativeboundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parent_id"

1571844
------verycreativeboundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

documentName25.pdf
------verycreativeboundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="documentName25.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

{yourbase64}
------verycreativeboundary--
```

in the header:

```
Content-Type multipart/form-data;boundary=----verycreativeboundary
```

the base64 I'm sending in **{yourbase64}** looks like this

> JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjI0IDAgb2JqCjw8L0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9GaXJzdCAyMS9MZW5ndGggMjY...

With this I managed to get the pdf to the server but the pdf only contains the base64 as a string. So the PDF is broken.
So something does not decode the base64 to pdf.

[image]

What am I missing that the pdf data gets correctly decoded in the pdf?
Maybe I am doing something wrong with Content-Transfer-Encoding?

The application I need to do this has only the RAW Body method availably so I can't use other methods.